# Formtastic Install breaking Bootstrap CSS stylesheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, formtastic

I'm using Rails 4. I'm installing formtastic and in the process following the Readme to make changes to the CSS. This is breaking my CSS - my pages are showing but without any formatting at all.

My Application.css file (I removed *= require_tree . per instructions on readme):

```
*= require_self
 # app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  *= require formtastic
  *= require my_formtastic_changes

# app/assets/stylesheets/ie6.css
  *= require formtastic_ie6

  # app/assets/stylesheets/ie7.css
  *= require formtastic_ie7
```

In application.html.erb note I commented out the previous stylesheet and added in a new link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%# stylesheet_link_tag "application",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

                                           <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "formtastic", "my_formtastic_changes" %>
  <!--[if IE 6]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie6' %><![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 7]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ie7' %><![endif]-->
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also added the stylesheet my_formtastic_changes.css.scss, an empty file. I experimented with adding/removing the formtastic and my_formtastic_changes references and using single and double quotes with the stylesheet references - no luck there.

Comment: if you remove `require_tree` then your css files won't get loaded. so no surprise your styles are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I left the require_tree . line out but had to add in

*= custom

So it loaded the custom stylesheet, including the bootstrap CSS.